# How to store JWT in cookies when using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authentication, cookies

I want to store JWT in cookies and set `HttpOnly flag` as well. is that possible with `react` ?

Comment: react has nothing to do with cookies. if you asked "is it possible with `javascript`" then it would be the exact same question

Comment: furthermore, jwts are typically added as cookies on the server side.. if its httpOnly then the client (react or whatever else) would not even be interacting with the cookie

Comment: I mean since `HttpOnly flag` enabled you cant access the `cookie` with `Javascript/React` so how can i get the token to send it with `Auth Headers` ?
I am really confused so pls could you explain more, i don't want to store it in `localStorage` due to `XSS` ..

Comment: As stated in comments this is done from your server side. react has nothing to do with it. You can also set token in header in your http request `authorization: Bearer <token>`. Not just cookies

Comment: Is there is a difference between setting the token in `Auth : bearer ...` and in `Cookies` ? or they are both dependent on each other, extract the token from the `cookie` then append it to `Auth Bearer <token>` to make requests ! @Maielo

Comment: No it is not. You can save token for example in `localStorage` or anywhere else :). Also on server side isntead of parsing cookies (which are usually bigger then header) you are parsing `header: Authorization` for token which then is decoded to get the data @Dodz

Comment: I also second @Maielo. you can set headers and store sensitive tokens in localStorage. If you want I can share a walkthrough of storing tokens.

Answer (score 0):

We can not set a cookie with the HttpOnly flag in the client side (this includes React, Angular and any other client framework).

The HttpOnly is an additional flag included in a Set-Cookie HTTP response header.

Using the HttpOnly flag when generating a cookie helps mitigate the risk of client side script accessing the protected cookie (if the browser supports it).

For more information read here: [HttpOnly](https://owasp.org/www-community/HttpOnly)